# Is it safe to override an NSObject method with a Category. Is at affect the system as well

Tags: objective-c, overriding, categories, nsobject

I it might sound a silly question, but I still afraid of doing so. Because I would like to override an NSObject method, namely addObserver: with a Category. Does it has an effect on other apps running on the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the Objective-C language currently allows you to use a category to override methods the class inherits, or even methods declared in the class interface, you are strongly discouraged from doing so. A category is not a substitute for a subclass.

About you question **Does it has an effect on other apps running on the system?**
Answer is **Big No.** It will affect only your app.

Answer (score 2):

Overriding `addObserver:forKeyPath:option:contex` is not a good idea. From a category implementation you can't call the method's `super` implementation, which basically means none of the observers will ever get added.

While this will only affect you app, it will do so at global level, meaning, even external frameworks will be affected, like UIKit or Fundation.

Comment: the point is to affect external frameworks.
I do call the original method using method_exchangeImplementations(originalAddObserver, myAddObserver); in the +load class method.

Comment: the reason I need this, is to add an observable array property of the properties.

So the new addObserve:, checks if I observe my 'properties' key, in case it does, than it observes every other properties, and manually notify the 'properties' key as well.

valuesAffectingKey... is not satisfactory, since it doesn't properly support a mutable property, like providing insertion or removal notifications.

Comment: or provide methods for scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Although category gives you a provision to add new methods to an existing class. Also you can override an existing methods but in few cases you may end up loosing the control as which method will be called!!!

And sometimes even you override a method the Frameworks methods are used and your method are not considered.

So I would suggest that you should not use same method name to override. You can use as, to differentiate :

`addObserverCustom:`